# Demo option for graphicx in memoir?

Tags: graphics, memoir

How can I activate the `demo` option for the [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package when using [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/)? Is there an equivalent option in memoir?

When I try:

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx
```

### Update (solved)

Memoir does not load `graphicx`, so the solution is to add `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` before any other package loads `graphicx`, as @egreg pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments point out, I can just add `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in the preamble. The option clash has nothing to do with memoir.

I am loading other packages in the preamble which is why I believe I had the option clash. The problem was resolved when I added `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` at the beginning of the preamble (before any other packages were added).

As a reference, I was adding these packages in the preamble:

```
mathpazo
tikz
ragged2e
fontenc
listings
hyperref
geometry
```

Comment: You have to insert that line before calling the other package that tries to load `graphicx`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that does not depend on the load order of the packages is to add demo as an option to the document class:

```
\documentclass[demo]{memoir}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```