# Vertical alignment of figure in multirow-cell inside tabu table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, tabu

We have a `tabu` table with figures and `\multirow` cell which contails a long figure (`XeLaTeX` is used). Minimal working example is in the end.

The Figure (arrow) is attached after the actual result.

Alignment rules

- column heading is centered (vertically and horizontally), colored and bold;
- 1,2,4 columns are centered vertically and left edge horizontally;
- 3,5 columns - centered both vertically and horizontally.

set by

```
\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep = 2mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
        |X[2,m]
        |X[1.5,m]
        |X[0.6, C,m]
        |X[2,m]
        |X[0.6, C,m]|
        }


\rowfont{\centering\bfseries\color{Blue}}
```

Column 5 has a Figure in multirow cell `\multirow{8}{*}{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{arrow.PNG}}`. It does not align to vertical center. Why? How to do it?

[image: Actual]

Arrow
[image: arrow]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0} 
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}


%--------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep = 2mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
        |X[2,m]
        |X[1.5,m]
        |X[0.6, C,m]
        |X[2,m]
        |X[0.6, C,m]|
        }


\rowfont{\centering\bfseries\color{Blue}}

\hline

Status
    & Visual indication
    & Symbol
    & Audible signal
    & Priority\\ \hline

Alarm active, not acknowledge 
    & Red, blinking 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High 
    \\ \hline

Alarm active, silenced 
    & Red, blinking 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png} 
    & Silent 
    & \multirow{8}{*}{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{arrow.PNG}} 
    \\    \tabucline{1-4}

Warnings active, not acknowledged
    & Yellowish orange, blinking 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 2 short audible signals, to be repeated at least once per 5 min or be replaced by an alarm 
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Warnings active, silenced 
    & Yellowish orange, blinking 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent 
    &   \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Rectified --- unacknowledged alarm
    & Visual indication 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent 
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Rectified --- unacknowledged warning
    & Visual indication 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent 
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Alarm active, acknowledged 
    & Visual indication 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Suppression of audible signal (silent)
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Warnings active, acknowledged
    & Visual indication 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent 
    &  \\ \hline

Caution active 
    & Yellow 
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent 
    & Low \\ \hline

Normal state 
    & Empty field 
    & None
    & Silent 
    &  \\ \hline

\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: These are likely to help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/centering-mutirow-text-in-a-table-whose-cells-contain-several-lines-of-text, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26080/how-can-i-achieve-proper-vertical-spacing-for-long-blocks-of-text-within-a-mult, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66596/vertical-alignment-in-multirow-using-cells-with-1-lines.

Comment: @Masroor, thank you for the response. We have pointed out a following vertical align of `\multirow` feature from the links: `fixup` argument (`\multirow{nrows}[bigstruts]{width}[fixup]{text}`). E.g. setting `\multirow{13}{*}[-5mm]{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{Fig/redesigned/arrow.png}}` moves our figure 5mm down. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66599/123948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- added package `[export]{adjustbox}` for determine image baseline in its vertical center
- corrected number of lines, which are spanned by `multirow`, to 13 (you need to count all lines in spanned rows)
- use option `=` for `\multirow`, which preserve column formatting in its cell
- added missing `graphicx` package (option demo is only for test purposes, since i haven't your image)

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


%--------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep = 2mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
        |X[2,m]
        |X[1.5,m]
        |X[0.6, C,m]
        |X[2,m]
        |X[0.6, C,m]|
        }
\rowfont{\centering\bfseries\color{Blue}}
    \hline
Status
    & Visual indication
    & Symbol
    & Audible signal
    & Priority\\ \hline

Alarm active, not acknowledge
    & Red, blinking
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High
    \\ \hline

Alarm active, silenced
    & Red, blinking
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent
    & \multirow{13}{=}{\includegraphics[height=8cm,             % <--- span 13 lines of text
                                       width=\linewidth,        % <---
                                       valign=m]{arrow.PNG}}    % <---
    \\    \tabucline{1-4}

Warnings active, not acknowledged
    & Yellowish orange, blinking
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 2 short audible signals, to be repeated at least once per 5 min or be replaced by an alarm
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Warnings active, silenced
    & Yellowish orange, blinking
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent
    &   \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Rectified --- unacknowledged alarm
    & Visual indication
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Rectified --- unacknowledged warning
    & Visual indication
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Alarm active, acknowledged
    & Visual indication
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Suppression of audible signal (silent)
    & \\ \tabucline{1-4}

Warnings active, acknowledged
    & Visual indication
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent
    &  \\ \hline

Caution active
    & Yellow
    & picture % \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{symbol.png}
    & Silent
    & Low \\ \hline

Normal state
    & Empty field
    & None
    & Silent
    &  \\ \hline

\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the response. We had to make following changes to get your solution works: 
1. to move `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` before all packages (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52886/123948). I know it is just for debugging, but directly copied MWE does not work for us and mabe somebody else);
2. in the `\multirow` command `=` is changed to `*`: `\multirow{13}{*}{\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=\linewidth,valign=m]{arrow.PNG}}` because with `=` an errors occur: `missing number, treated as zero` and `illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`;

Comment: We also didn't found `=` parameter for `\multirow` in docs http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/multirow/multirow.pdf

Comment: @AndreiLosenkov, this parameter was introduced by last version (about ear old) of  `multirow` package. please, update it. given link gives to old information. rather see http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf

Comment: oh, okay. But it works with `*` also for us. Thank you for the support!

Comment: @AndreiLosenkov, are you sure? without use ˙{=}˙the `\linewidth` (which I use to determine image width) is not well defined. in your particular case your image is (luckily) narrowed then original column width.

Comment: When the latest MiKTeX version was installed `=` started to work as expected.

Comment: @AndreiLosenkov, i'm glad to hear this. happy tex-ing!