# Vertically align a figure within a multirow environment of a table

Tags: multirow, includegraphics

I am using multirow to merge two rows of a table - I want the figure in that column to be vertically aligned.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c l}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \multirow{2}{*}{ $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}}$}\\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\end{tabular}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:}  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7222/70816) with both the raisebox and vcenter options by using

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}}
```

and

```
\multirow{2}{*}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}}$}
```

as well as

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth,height=4cm,valign=m]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
```

with `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` added to the preamble as suggested by [this answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387070/70816)

without anything changing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use `\multirow` here. A simple `\raisebox`,  with the optional arguments to fool LaTeX will do the trick.

*Unrelated*: don't insert a `center` environment in floats, as it adds a supplementry, usually unwanted, vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} \centering
\begin{tabular}{c c l}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\raisebox{-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} & %
\end{tabular}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `minipages`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{ma caption}
  \label{fig:mylabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `multirow` is not necessary. If I understand your problem description correctly, one could use the `graphbox` package (or any other similar package) to achieve the desired effect in a simple way.

## Output

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth,height=4cm,align=c,vsmash,vshift=-.45em]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\\
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\end{tabular}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the `vshift` part is not an optimal solution. I hope someone will improve it.